# Validate decimal greater than 1 with regex

Tags: regex

I want to validate that a number with three optional integer and four digits mandatory after the decimal point is greater than 1. For example:

```
0.0000     [No]
0.9999     [No]
1.0000     [No]
1.0009     [Yes]
01.0000    [No]
01.0009    [Yes]
001.0000   [No]
011.0000   [Yes]
222.0000   [Yes]
000.9999   [No]
```

I have been created this regex:

```
  (?!^1*$)(?!^1*\.0*$)^(?:[1-9]|\d\d\d)(?:\.\d{4,4})$
```

But it doesn't work for all the cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this regex to allow up to 3 digits before `.` and 4 digits after `.` to match values greater than `1` only:

```sh
^(?!0*1\.0+$)(?=0*[1-9])\d{1,3}\.\d{4}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jq4Lud/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!0*1\.0+$)`: Positive Lookahead condition to assert that we don't have a case of optional zeroes followed by `1.0000`
- `(?=0*[1-9])`: Positive Lookahead condition to assert that we have at least on non-zero digit ahead
- `\d{1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 digits
- `\.`: Match a `.`
- `\d{4}`: Match 4 digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 4):

If supported, you might use a negative lookahead to exclude some of the possible matches:

```
^(?!0*1\.0+$|\d{4}\.)0*[1-9]\d*\.\d{4}$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, not directly to the right

  - `0*1\.0+$` Match optional zeroes, a dot and 1 or more zeroes
  - `|` or
  - `\d{4}\.` Match 4 digits and a dot
- `)` Close lookahead
- `0*[1-9]\d*` Match optional zeroes, a digit 1-9 and optional digits
- `\.\d{4}` match a . and 4 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nfKNt1/1)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use:

```sh
^(?!0*\.|0*1\.0*$)\d{1,3}\.\d{4}$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGQWm2/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `0*\.` - Prevent 0+ leading zero's upto a literal dot;
  - `|` - Or:
  - `0*1\.0*$` - Prevent 0+ leading zero's up to a 1 followed by a literal dot and trailing zero's until string ends.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `\d{1,3}\.\d{4}` - 1-3 Leading digits, a literal dot and 4 trailing digits.
- `$` - End string anchor.